# Terminal mp3 player with tunable song speed

Tags: music, macos

As the title. I know there have been many similar questions on this, but none of them mention the key feature I want: change the speed of the song. Any idea? To prove that I'm a serious "Terminal Guy" and "Music Lover": (I have spent 10,000 hours on terminal things, mostly NeoVim)

[image]

Comment: What is a terminal mp3 player for you? One used by a command line interface like mpd or should it have an UI but just based on terminal characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [MPV](https://mpv.io/), "a free, open source, and cross-platform media player". The volume can be controlled via the [keyboard](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#keyboard-control), using "[" and "]" keys etc.

I believe mpv is a fork of mplayer.

Comment: Is it possible to play music via URL without installing many strange ffmpeg-like dependencies (and failed)? While I'm using mplayer, the problem with it is that I don't know how to play music directly from (youtube-)URL.

Comment: Wow, it has a `--no-video` option. And URL is supported by default!